# To ensure the dependency package location is in the same as its dependent package

Tags: cmake, dependencies

Is it automatically the default that a package location of recursive dependency is in the same as its dependent package above or we have to ensure, i.e. tell/instruct Cmake, to refer the recursed dependency package location?

the `foobar` package is to be found

```
foreach(FOOB   foo  bar)
   find_library(FOO_${FOOB}_LIBRARY   ${FOOB}
        HINTS
          "/usr"
        PATH_SUFFIXES
            lib/
       )
    if(FOO_${FOOB}_LIBRARY)
        list(APPEND FOO_LIBRARIES ${FOO_${FOOB}_LIBRARY})
    endif()
   endforeach()
…
…

find_package_handle_standard_args(foobar
    REQUIRED_VARS
        FOO_LIBRARIES
)
```

and
foo.so depends: `baz.so`
bar.so depends: `baz.so`

baz.so will be automatically found under /usr/lib by Cmake rule, or what syntax to ensure and order Cmake to do it?

Comment: "baz.so will be automatically found under /usr/lib by Cmake rule" - The code you show doesn't search for `baz.so`, so I don't understand what "automatically found" means. "`foo.so` depends: `baz.so`" - That is, `foo.so` is **linked** with `baz.so`? If yes, then linking with `foo.so` will automatically links with `baz.so`. This is not a CMake feature but a linker feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, CMake will not search for `baz.so` automatically. If `foo.so` and `bar.so` have their RPATH set correctly or are located in a global linker search path (which they are in your case) then linking against `foo.so` or `bar.so` will work just fine without it. If they are missing the RPATH and are not in a global linker search path then the linker will complain that it can't find `baz.so` at link time.

If the RPATH of `foo.so` or `baz.so` is not set then you should add the `-rpath-link` linker flag even if on your system they are in a global search path because other consumers of your project might have them installed in some other directory. This can be done via

```
# assumes foo was found, and both foo and bar are in the same directory
get_filename_component(LIBFOO_DIR ${FOO_foo_LIBRARY DIRECTORY)
target_link_options(<target-name>
  INTERFACE
    LINKER:-rpath-link,${LIBFOO_DIR}
)
```

where `<target-name>` is the name of the imported target you use for the `libfoo` library.

Comment: It's it? Would you perfect the answer for the real needing case: the foobar is a Debian Testing package needed/invoked by an App on top of Stable, so mandatory not to touch, make a mess with the Stable. Logically the need is a special dir. containing any package (i.e. foobar) along with all dependencies to be correctly invoked by the App and it'd run smoothly, while keeping the OS from breaking harmful Testing installation

Comment: @memekindah I'm sorry I couldn't follow, probably because I don't know how Debian Testing and Stable work as I have never used Debian before. If you have a special directory where `foo.so`,`bar.so`, their dependencies and the application will be installed you need to make sure that all libraries have their RPATH/RUNPATH set to `$ORIGIN` as otherwise they might use system libraries instead of the libraries in the same directory, or you need to set an RPATH for the application (RPATH is propagated to dependencies, RUNPATH is not).

Comment: [This](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) gives a pretty good overview what the RPATH/RUNPATH are and how to set them via CMake.